# How to prevent inconsistent 'load' event firing from <object> (SVG)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am loading an SVG via an `<object>` tag.  I am waiting to add all my event listeners until the object has loaded

**Example**

```
document.querySelector('object').addEventListener('load', function () 
{
  console.log('loaded')
}, false)
```

However, the results are very inconsistent.  About one in nine times the `load` event is not firing at all and "loaded" is not being printed to the console.

This is strange because all of the content is being served from a local server and looking at the console there are no errors. Additionally the whole SVG image always loads so I am a little confused.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Additionally, is this the correct way to listen for an SVG embedded in an object to load?

I also see the [SVGLoad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/SVGLoad) event but there is almost no documentation for it and I am not sure if it works with the `object` tag or not.

Comment: SVGLoad has been deprecated. Your problem most certainly comes from the cache. Since you're doing `document.querySelector('object')`, I'll guess that your element is directly written in the HTML markup, with its data attribute. In webkit, the event will already have fired before you attached it. The solution is then to reset the `data` attribute once you attached the event listener. `var obj = document.querySelector('object'); obj.addEventListener('load', yourFunc); obj.data = obj.data;`

Comment: @Kaiido this is happening even when I have `disable HTTP cache` set in Firefox.  Could it be something else. But I didn't know that trick of resetting the data.  Interesting!

Comment: Since it comes from localhost, it could also be a simple race condition. But the fact that it happens on FF is indeed strange, I always only saw this behavior on webkit browsers. Are you waiting for the `document.onload` event before attaching your event handler ? That could explain it.

Comment: I wasn't before. Now I am and your solution is working.

Comment: So race condition and indeed a dupe ;-)